# How to make THREE.Mesh look volumetric with WebVR?

Tags: javascript, three.js, oculus, webvr

I'm working on porting an existing three.js project to WebVR + Oculus Rift. Basically, this app takes an STL file as input, creates a `THREE.Mesh` based on it and renders it on an empty scene. I managed to make it work in Firefox Nightly with VREffect plugin to three.js and VRControls. A problem I have is models rendered in VR aren't really 3D. Namely, when I move the HMD back and forth an active 3D model doesn't get closer/farther, and I can't see different sides of the model. It looks like the model is rather a flat background image stuck to its position. If I add `THREE.AxisHelper` to the scene, it is transformed correctly when HMD is moved.

Originally, `THREE.OrbitControls` were used in the app and models were rotated and moved properly.

There's quite some amount of source code so I'll post some snippets on demand.

Comment: That's really odd. Are you still using OrbitControls? Is the model added to the scene directly, or is it added to the camera? It sounds like you've added the model to the camera, so it moves with the camera, which means you can't see it from different perspectives.

Comment: you probably need to use the `DeviceOrientationControls`

Comment: @brianpeiris, yeah, exactly. I have an impression of this, but I add the mesh to a scene, then I add camera to the scene. Which is kind of strange because I couldn't find any demo where it's recommended to do. But, in my case camera doesn't move at all if don't add it to the scene.
And I don't use OrbitControls because when VR mode enabled there's no cursor at the Oculus displays, so mouse events are ignored. Actually, I'd like to use OrbitControls because they can come in handy sometimes, but it seems not possible with the current WebVR implementation.

Comment: @gaitat, it seems that `DeviceOrientationControls` don't work with Oculus. At least, demos that I could find on the Internet are static regardless of Oculus position and orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that technically there was no problem. The issue was essentially with different scales of my models and Oculus movements. When `VRControls` is used with default settings, it reports a position of HMD as it reads it from Oculus, in meters. So, the range of movements of my head could barely exceed 1 m, whereas average sizes of my models are about a few dozens of their own units. When I used them altogether at the same scene, it was like a viewer is an ant looking at a giant model. Naturally, the ant have to walk a while to see another side of the model. That's why it seemed like not a 3D body.

Fortunately, there's a `scale` property of `VRControls` that should be used for adjusting scale of HMD movements. When I set it to about 30, everything works pretty well.

Thanks to [@brianpeiris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22417/brianpeiris)'s comment, I decided to check coordinates of the model and camera once again to make sure they're not knit with each other. And, it led me to the solution.